# Upload any file in django

Tags: python, django, file-upload

I was trying to create a function for upload file in Django. First time I running my code, it's cannot upload a file. So, I was trying to improve my code and what I got its error. I thought the error it's weird because I always used that and I never get an error. I'll show my code.

**models.py**

```
class UploadFiles(models.Model):
    File = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'Images/', default='Images/')
```

**views.py**

```
def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFile(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = UploadFile()
    return render(request, 'girl/upload.html', {'form': form})
```

**forms.py**

```
class UploadFile(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    file = forms.FileField
```

**upload.html**

```
{% extends 'girl/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit">Upload</button>
    </form>

    <p><a href="{% url '/' %}">Return to home</a></p>
{% endblock %}
```

**error:**

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for '/' not found. '/' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^cat/upload/$', views.upload_file, name='uploads')
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what error do you get? Please post it (edit your question). Also, is it a typo? In your `views.py` you use "UploadFile" instead of "UploadFiles" model

Comment: I forgot to display the error. I already display the error.

Comment: I think "UploadFiles" is for model and "UploadFile" is for forms. @ThomasSchwärzl

Comment: please post your `urls.py`

Comment: Done. urls.py already post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the line the error is

```
    <p><a href="{% url '/' %}">Return to home</a></p>
```

Change it to

```
    <p><a href="{% url 'name of the route' %}">Return to home</a></p>
```

And in your forms to

```
   class UploadFile(forms.ModelForm)
        class Meta:
               model=UploadFiles
               fields ='__all__'
```

Comment: I solved it. i change '/' with the name of urls. but i got a new error. AttributeError: 'UploadFile' object has no attribute 'save'. Can you help me out